# What are good Information System design resources?

Tags: design, web-applications

After taking a class about information systems, I want to find additional resources for learning the various patterns, concepts, and examples of their implementation. The course did focus on Martin Fowler's Principles of Enterprise Application Architecture and had a project that attempted to implement some of them.

Basically, where can I learn more about Information System design and implementation?

Comment: -1 None real prog needs dis crap. [and English language either]

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are looking for examples from a Coders point of view - this book - [Core J2EE Patterns](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131422464) helped me a lot when I was first starting out developing Enterprise applications in Java.  It's examples are specific to Java, but they can easily be applied to most OOP languages.  Of course, there is always the Gang of Four [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201633612).

However, if you are looking for more high level concepts... go no further than Fowlers own [Domain Specific Languages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321712943) or something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470684208).  Also, it never hurts to read classics like Mythical Man-Month or CODE Complete to get overview of what it will take to design, develop and deliver enterprise solutions. (Even if those last two are not specific to enterprise development - but do apply).

Also, one last point - everyone should read this [Peopleware](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0932633439).  It really brings home how without the right people, not design will ever be successfully developed and delivered.